# Trouble Connecting To Wearable Data Layer

Tags: android, android-asynctask, timeout, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I am trying to connect to the data layer on the wearable device using an `Activity` that implements `DataApi.DataListener`. In `onStart()` the device connects to the Google API Client, and `onConnected()` is called. From `onConnected()` I call another method that sends a message to the handheld to update the data, and starts a new `AsyncTask` to get the data from the data layer. This is my `Activity`:

```
public class DataLayerActivity extends Activity implements DataApi.Listener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private ArrayList<myObject> mObjects = new ArrayList<>();

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Wearable.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if(null != mGoogleApiClient && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Wearable.DataApi.removeListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        } super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Wearable.DataApi.addListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        requestUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        Timber.d("Connection Suspended");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Timber.d("Connection Failed with result: " + result);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {
    }

    private void requestUpdate() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mGoogleApiClient).await();
                for(Node node : nodes.getNodes()) {
                    Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(getGoogleApiClient(), node.getId(), "/path", null).setResultCallback(onMessageResult());
                }
            }
        }).start();

        try {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("/path");
            mObjects = new FetchDataTask(this).execute(uri).get();
        } catch(InterruptedException | ExecutionException exception) {
            Timber.e(exception, "Fetch Data Failed");
        }
    }

    protected ResultCallback<MessageApi.SendMessageResult> onMessageResult() {
        if(!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            Timber.d("Failed to Connect with status " + result.getStatus());
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the `FetchDataTask`:

```
public class FetchDataTask extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, ArrayList<myObject>> {

    private Context mContext;

    private ArrayList<myObject> mObjects = new ArrayList<>();

    public FetchDataTask(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<myObject> doInBackground(Uri... params) {
        GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(mContext).addApi(WearableAPI).build();

        ConnectionResult connectionResult = googleApiClient.blockingConnect(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if(!connectionResult.isSuccess() || !googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Timber.e("Failed to Connect with error code: " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
            return null;
        }

        ...

        return mObjects;
    }
}
```

The connection result always returns with [error code](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult) 14, which is a connection timeout. So I tried passing the already connected `GoogleApiClient` from `DataLayerActivity` as a parameter to `FetchDataTask`, and using that for the processes. But when I make a call to `Wearable.DataApi.getDataItem().await()` or `Werable.NodeApi.getLocalNode().await()` within `doInBackground()`, `await()` never finishes, and my app stalls. But I never get any error messages from `onConnectionSuspended()` or `onConnectionFailed()`. I cannot figure out why the connection to the data layer times out in my `AsyncTask`. I know this can be done, as it is done this way in the [AttractionsActivity](http://developer.android.com/samples/XYZTouristAttractions/Wearable/src/com.example.android.xyztouristattractions/ui/AttractionsActivity.html) in the XYZTouristAttractions sample application.

Answer (score 0):

Quickly looking at your code, I can see a few issues:

- In the FetchDataTask, in doInBackground, you build a googleApiClient but you never called connect()to establish a connection
- In the requestUpdate(), it seems there are unmatched braces, etc. Also, for the thread that you built there, I don't see you ever call "start()" on it.
- Whenever you call await() on any of the asynchronous calls, make sure you specify a timeout so that it doesn't get stuck forever and after that, check to make sure the call was successful before using the result.

Comment: I did not notice that I never called `connect()`, that would seem to cause a problem. But I added `googleApiClient.connect()` to `doInBackground()`, and I still get the same timeout error code. `AsyncTask` does not have a `start()` method, I believe `execute()` functions similarly. As for `await()`, this was really just for testing purposes, I plan on adding timeout callbacks in the finished code.

Comment: Also, I just looked into it further, it looks like `googleApiClient.blockingConnect(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` acts as `connect()` call. Documented here: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html

Comment: You are right about the mismatched braces and the `start()` call, I thought you meant the `AsyncTask`. When I copied the code over it got a little jumbled, I must have missed that when I tried to fix it. It was correct in the original code, I just fixed it in the question.